# Z3 Int not defined error

Tags: python, z3

I am trying to use Z3 library from python however it does not work. It gives an error Int is not defined.

I installed the z3 module using pip and as you can see, there is no error message thrown when I import the lib. I am using Mac OS X and python version 2.7.6

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> x = Int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Int' is not defined
```

Comment: z3 appears to be an interface to a C++ library - have you installed the library it's trying to use? https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 has instructions

Comment: Did you install the package called angr-z3 or a different one?

Comment: Did you install `z3-solver`?

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem at the beginning.

The cause of the problem is that you didn't install the right package.

The right package name is `z3-solver`.

To install it:

```
pip install z3-solver
```

Comment: I was using VSCode, had to restart to resolve this. Leaving this comment here for anyone trying this in the future, DON'T forget to restart!