# Attrubute error, z3 has no attribute Ints

Tags: python, attributes, z3

I am doing symbolic execution in Python using the z3 module. At some part of the code, exec is being used to invoke calling z3 function. The code snippet is as follows:

```
def can_be_satisfied(n):
 path = get_path(n)
 my_names, path =to_single_assignment(path)
 s1 = "%s = z3.Ints('%s')" % (', '.join(my_names), ' '.join(my_names))
 exec(s1, globals(), locals())
 s = z3.Solver()
 s2 = 's.add(%s)' % (', '.join([tosrc(i) for i in path]))
 print(s2)
 exec(s2, globals(), locals())
 if s.check() == z3.sat:
    print("sat:", s.model())
    return True
 else:
    return False
```

As I saw in the documentation of z3 module for Python (http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/guide-examples.htm), it contains the attribute 'Ints'. However, after the execution of the program, the following error is generated by the snippet:

```
File "code/symbolic_concolic_egt/symbolic/symbolic.py", line 69, in can_be_satisfied
    exec(s1, globals(), locals())
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>     
AttributeError: module 'z3' has no attribute 'Ints'
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem is welcomed.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you import the Z3 module in the string that is passed to `exec`? In general, `exec` is not a good way run Z3 queries as it is very tightly constrained; for instance the stack space available is absolutely tiny.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried to import the module z3 inside the string and I am still getting the error. I will look for an alternative to exec

Comment: How did you install Z3? Try `pip install z3-solver` (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866935 )

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was with conflicting packages.
I had `z3` and `z3-solver` both installed.
After removing `z3` package I was able to use `z3` without issues.